# Javascript Regex: Need something like AND combination of two Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, backbone.js

I need a Regular Expression which can check two things:

1. A string does not contain special characters like - `'"}{`
2. A string does not contain backslash `\` at the end.

I am able to form a regex for both of them separately like below:

For 1) `/^[^'"}{]$/` - This will ensure that characters inside the bracket will not be there any where in the string.

For 2) `/[\\\]$/` - This will ensure that the string doesn't end with a backslash.

I have a task in which I cannot have two regex, I need only one regex. And I want both the regex to be checked. As far as I have understood, the '|' symbol works as an OR operator. Is there a way in which I can check both the conditions using just one regex ?

**Update:**

It's an old application which still uses Backbone JS and the code in which I am using the regex looks similar to below:

```
schema :{
userPass : {
title: i18n['user.password'], 
type: "Password", 
validators: ['required', {type: "regexp", regexp: /^[^'"}{]{1,24}$/, message: i18n['user.pass.notvalid']}]}
```

Now, there's a new requirement to not allow backslash `\` only at the end. It can be there in the beginning or the middle.

Comment: Your regexps imply you are using them in a method that tests a single char, not a sequence of chars. You need to show your code that is most likely to need updating, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Updated my question.

Comment: Ok, doesn't `/^(?!.*\\$)[^'"}{]{1,24}$/` work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Yes, the above regex is working. The one given by Edward in the answer is also working. Which one do you think is better ?

Comment: Mine has a length check.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Agree with you. With the regex given by Edward, I am not able to restrict the length of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?!.*\\$)[^'"}{]{1,24}$/
```

It matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\\$)`  - no `\` at the end of string allowed
- `[^'"}{]{1,24}` - 1 to 24 chars other than `'`, `"`, `{` and `}`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

AND Try `/^(?!.*['"}{])(?!.*\\$)/`
if at least 1 char try `/^(?!.*['"}{])(?!.*\\$)./`

Comment: I'll try your regex and let you know if it works. Thanks

Comment: Edward, With your regex, I am not able to restrict the length.

Comment: Whet length ? Illustrate `.{5,17}`

Comment: AND defined a two sequenced assertions, try `^[^'"}{]{5,17}$(?<!\\)` or `^([^'"}{\\]|\\(?!$)){5,17}$` if no AND